# Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process

Tags: apache2, mod-wsgi, postgresql-9.5, trac

I am using mod_wsgi with apache2.

```
[Thu Aug 29 10:50:48.050923 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 24309] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

From the above line, you can see that mod_wsgi version is 4.3.0 and apache 2.4.18.

I am running a web application made of Trac framework. And a Django app. Both of them interconnected with some linking. And a Zend app is also part of the overall system.

The major problem is that the app goes unusable by producing "Gateway time out" errors.

When examined, I found 'apache2' is taking too much of CPU. Sometimes 'postgresql' takes too much of CPU. I am not sure why this is happening. In a hope, I tried restarting the services apache and postgresql but it doesn't help much. The same problem continues.

```
30820 postgres  20   0  314748  46120  42936 R  98.3  1.1   0:26.04 postgres
```

Above line is part of 'top' command in which postgres uses 98.3% of CPU.

```
Below is my virtual host script. 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.domain.com
WSGIDaemonProcess prismdjango user=www-data group=www-data home=/opt/Production/CustomPlugins/CommonPlugin/PRISMDJANGO
WSGIDaemonProcess prismnew user=www-data group=www-data home=/opt/PRISM30/

WSGIScriptAlias /audittool /opt/Production/CustomPlugins/CommonPlugin/PRISMDJANGO/PRISMDJANGO/wsgi.py
WSGIScriptAlias /api /opt/Production/CustomPlugins/CommonPlugin/PRISMDJANGO/PRISMDJANGO/wsgi.py
WSGIScriptAlias /project /opt/Production/CustomPlugins/CommonPlugin/PRISMDJANGO/PRISMDJANGO/wsgi.py
WSGIScriptAlias /accounts /opt/PRISM30/PRISM30/wsgi.py

WSGIProcessGroup prismdjango
WSGIProcessGroup prismnew

Alias /Audittool/static /opt/Production/CustomPlugins/CommonPlugin/PRISMDJANGO/Audittool/static
Alias /user_deactivate /var/www/html/user_deactivate
Alias /contractual_requirements/static /opt/PRISM30/contractual_requirements/static/

<Directory /opt/PRISM30>
    WSGIProcessGroup prismnew
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Require all granted
    Options ExecCGI
    AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    #AllowOverride All
     #Require all granted
   <Files PRISM30/wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
   </Files>
</Directory>


<Directory /opt/Production/CustomPlugins/CommonPlugin/PRISMDJANGO>
    WSGIProcessGroup prismdjango
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Require all granted
    Options ExecCGI
    AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
#Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
#AllowOverride All
#Require all granted
<Files PRISMDJANGO/wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>    
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


DocumentRoot /opt/TracProjects
WSGIDaemonProcess prism user=www-data group=www-data home=/opt/TracProjects
WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/share/trac/trac.wsgi
WSGIProcessGroup prism
<Directory "/opt/TracProjects">
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    #Options Indexes ExecCGI
    #DirectoryIndex index.cgi
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all granted
</IfModule>
</Directory>
<Location /opt/TracProjects>
WSGIProcessGroup prism
</Location>
# TRAC ENV PARENT DIRECTORIES SETUP

DirectoryIndex index.php index.cgi

Alias /authtimesheet "/var/www/ZendApp/public"

#DocumentRoot /var/www/ZendApp/public
#SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory /var/www/ZendApp/public>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php
AllowOverride All
#Order allow,deny
#Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

From apache log file,

```
[Wed Aug 28 18:31:25.478081 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23046] [client 172.24.188.116:36348] Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'prism': /usr/share/trac/trac.wsgi, referer: http://subdomain.domain.com

[Wed Aug 28 18:34:30.461158 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 24138] [client 172.24.188.116:36576] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'prism': /usr/share/trac/trac.wsgi, referer: http://subdomain.domain.com
```

I just want to get rid of this Time outs!Hope this Truncated or oversized response would be of another clue.

Below line is from postgresql log.

```
could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer.
```

Comment: FYI: You'll probably get a better answer for this question on Superuser.